# Очистка MediaPlayer

Tags: android

Использую один MediaPlayer. Даю ему разный звук при нажатии на каждую из 2 кнопок вот так:

```
@Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                switch(v.getId()) {
                case R.id.flats_btn1:                       
                    if (flats_m == null || !flats_m.isPlaying()) {
                        flats_m = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), R.raw.flat_m_10);
                        flats_m.start();
                    }
                    break; 
                case R.id.flats_btn2:                       
                    if (flats_m == null || !flats_m.isPlaying()) {
                        flats_m = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), R.raw.flat_m_20);
                        flats_m.start();
                    }
                    break;

            }                   

                flats_m.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() { 
                    @Override 
                    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer flats_m1) {                                                    
                        flats_m.release(); 
                        Log.i("flats_m", "MediaPlayer очищен"); 

                    }
                });  

       }
```

Еще делаю так, чтобы после проигрывания плеер очищался. При первом нажатии на кнопку все нормально, но при следующем нажатии вылетает ошибка:

```
08-21 23:27:01.784: E/AndroidRuntime(1442): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-21 23:27:01.784: E/AndroidRuntime(1442): java.lang.IllegalStateException
08-21 23:27:01.784: E/AndroidRuntime(1442):     at android.media.MediaPlayer.isPlaying(Native Method)
08-21 23:27:01.784: E/AndroidRuntime(1442):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
08-21 23:27:01.784: E/AndroidRuntime(1442):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
08-21 23:27:01.784: E/AndroidRuntime(1442):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
08-21 23:27:01.784: E/AndroidRuntime(1442):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-21 23:27:01.784: E/AndroidRuntime(1442):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-21 23:27:01.784: E/AndroidRuntime(1442):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
08-21 23:27:01.784: E/AndroidRuntime(1442):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-21 23:27:01.784: E/AndroidRuntime(1442):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-21 23:27:01.784: E/AndroidRuntime(1442):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
08-21 23:27:01.784: E/AndroidRuntime(1442):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
08-21 23:27:01.784: E/AndroidRuntime(1442):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

В чем может быть причина? И вообще, нужно ли очищать плеер, если он не нужен?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Просто обнулите плеер после `release()`

```
flats_m.release();
flats_m = null;
```

Comment: Спасибо! Еще такой вопрос: нужно ли очищать плеер, если он не нужен?

Comment: @turok09, ну, вообще говорят что надо. Во всяком случае так точно лучше, чем не очищать

Comment: А вот в этом месте должен же быть другой плеер, например, flats_m1? public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer flats_m1) {

Comment: @turok09, в данном случае ое переменные ссылаются на один и тот же объект. Т.е. разницы нет

Comment: Просто, если использовать flats_m, то возникает ошибка, а если flats_m1, то все нормально

Comment: @turok09, другим не видно ваших ошибок. Если у вас ошибка - пишите какая

Comment: Смысла нет, так как с flats_m1 все в порядке

Comment: @turok09, узнать почему падает/не компилируется - всегда имеет смысл

Comment: Лог ошибки такой же, как и выше. Я так понял, что очищается и приравнивается к нулю тот плеер flats_m, который следит за окончанием настоящего flats_m, поэтому ошибка такая же

Comment: Хотел еще спросить: нужно ли перед очисткой плеера ставить его на стоп? flats_m.stop(); flats_m.release();

Comment: @turok09, stop, думаю, не обязательно.